# Unable to program detection behavior on Webview and xml Textview

Tags: android, xml, layout, webview, textview

I am trying to change the visibility of my textview inside onCreate method, but I cant seem to get a handle for it. Or, perhaps something else is wrong. Also, the getUrl() from the WebView class is not behaving as it should. It seems that it detects the url i am looking for after i leave the page with the url i am trying to detect. After reading the documentation, it made it somewhat clear based on the definition of the method getUrl(). Here is what the documentation says: **"Gets the URL for the current page. This is not always the same as the URL passed to WebViewClient.onPageStarted because although the load for that URL has begun, the current page may not have changed."**
Here's what I mean: 
I click on "link within the webpage that has url am trying to detect call it url5", then pressed back button, then click on "some other link within webpage call it url6" . Now, when I go back out of link with url6, the link for url5 is detected and I should be able to setVisibility of my textview as VISIBLE, which i tried but nothing happens. Well, here's my code. Please advise of anything that I might be doing wrong.

```
"xml format"
<RelativeLayout>
 specifications for the relative layout...
<TextView>
android:visibility="invisible"
other specifications such as match_parent for both height and width
/>
<LinearLayout>
specifications of linear layout...
<LinearLayout/>
</RelativeLayout>

"inside onCreate"
relative_layout =  (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.content_main, null); 
text_view = (TextView)relative_layout.findViewById(R.id.text);

WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
w.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

//outside of onCreate inside private class MyWebViewClient
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
if(W.getUrl().equals("url I want to detect") ||
   W.getUrl().equals("another url I want to detect")){

  text_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //HOWEVER NOTHING SHOWS AT ALL  
  relative_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}    

        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {    
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && w.canGoBack()) {
    if(text_view.isShown()){
    w.goBack();
    text_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    relative_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else w.goBack();

    return true;
}    
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Comment: your textview is inside relative_layout. and in the code you are setting relative layout invisible. So your textview wont display anything because its parent "relative layout " is invisible

Comment: seems like a plausible answer. I've never thought of it this way. so what I should do is set all the children of my relative layout as invisible not the whole layout. Thanks for the enlightenment. I am new to working with xml layouts. Up to now, all my layouts have been created with java code. Or better yet, I should just display my textview, since it has match_parent for both width and height. It would cover all the children. @Roon13